# Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'funcao')

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, ejs

Hi everyone i'm creating a site whit javascript and i need authentication to check if is an admin or a customer to redirect him for different ways , but i have a problem , when i try to check the **Cannot read properties of undefined**.

My **AuthorizatioCheck**

```
module.exports =  async function(req, res, next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
     const utilizador = req.Utilizador;
     if(utilizador.funcao==='admin'){
         next();
     }else{
          res.redirect('back');
     }
}else{
    res.redirect('/utilizadores/login');
}
```

};

**The model**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const utilizadorSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    nome:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    funcao:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'customer'
    },

    fidelizacao:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
        

    },
    carrinho:[{
        livro:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Livro",
        },
        quantidade:{
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1
        }
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Utilizador", utilizadorSchema);
```

**The error**

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'funcao')

```
at module.exports (C:\Users\cardo\Desktop\book--store--nodejs-master\middleware\checkAuthorization.js:4:24)
```

Can someone fix me ? i'm watching the code for hours and can't figure out...

Comment: What is the value of `req.Utilizador`?

Comment: what is the value of req ? can you console log this ?

Comment: @NileshMishra undefined , with the console.log

Comment: somehow your data is not populating in the authorization file, so again console log utilizadorSchema in the model file before export

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `utilizador` (=> `req.Utilizador`) is `undefined` and therefore `funcao` is not a valid property of it.

To fix this specific error I suggest using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining);

```
if (utilizador?.funcao === 'admin') {
    next();
} else {
    res.redirect('back');
}
```

Next you should probably check why `req.Utilizador` is not being defined, assuming it should be in your application logic.

Comment: I know he says undefined ... im trying to solve this problem , i already checked all the code , but probably i cant find the error because it was me doing it

Comment: @NicolasSousa We would need to see the code which should be defining `req.Utilizador` in order to help further.
Also, could it be `req.utilizador` (lower case)?

Comment: i changed to lower case same result , which part u want me to post?

Comment: @NicolasSousa Please add to the post the express middleware function/module which is responsible for using the `Utilizador` model you've shared and adding it to the request object (`req`).